# Angularjs list and detail view

Tags: angularjs

this is my basic scenario. For a list of items (summary view) i want to show details view of item that got clicked on the same page.

I took this jsfiddle [example](http://jsfiddle.net/pkozlowski_opensource/65Cxv/7/) and transformed it into this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ptGWr/8/). If you look at the behavior it does work for first time but it is not consistent.

Maybe someone can help me with this, or suggest a better approach. I would like to have a different controller for managing the list and a different controller to handle the detail view.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One way of transforming the example (provided that you want to use ngSwitch) would be:

```
<ul ng-controller="ListController">
    <li ng-repeat="item in items" ng-controller="ItemController">
        <div ng-click="open(item)">{{item.content}}</div>        
    </li>
    <hr>
    <ng-switch on="anyItemOpen()">
     <div ng-switch-when="true">
         <div ng-controller="ItemController">
             {{opened.name}}: overlay: tweet, share, pin
         </div>  
         <a ng-click="close()">close</a>         
     </div>
    </ng-switch>   
</ul>
```

And here is the working jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pkozlowski_opensource/sJdzt/4/

Your jsFiddle didn't work since you were trying to reference `item` created in the ngRepeat scope (and thus not available outside of the ngRepeat).

Comment: Thanks a lot. Why i coded this way was because i want ItemController to manipulate the item that gets selected. Can I pass the opened item into a local scope of ItemController and then manipulate the item from ItemController Scope methods?

Comment: @Chandermani: just fire an event that contains the opened item, and catch the event from the ItemController.