# AngularJS tab-like behavior for list/detail view on same page where form needs to change based on selected list item

Tags: forms, angularjs

I have a list/detail page which I've based off of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12469742/angularjs-list-and-detail-view) question.

It works perfectly for displaying the information, however, my detail view in this case needs to be a form.

So my question (which I really hope some of you smart folks can help with) is two-fold:

1. How can I add an active class on the list item I clicked, and remove it once I've "closed" the detail view, or clicked on another list item?
2. How can I update the form in the detail view, and have the user potentially make changes to that form, and still have it update the correct item in my model?

Imagine a list of phones on the left, with an edit form on the right. The user would choose a phone on the left, change the number in the form on the right, and hit save.

I come from a jQuery background, and I'm still trying to get my head around AngularJS.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can see most of the issues you ask about in this very [basic demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/1MUNiD0SNKBj4Sq2dncL?p=preview)

Comment: validation concepts built into angular are really powerful aslo. Bit of a leraning curve but there are lots of tutorials

Comment: Yea quite a steap learning curve I must say -- but worth it so far

Comment: You should probably answer you own question to close this. Just put a link to the page that helped you most and a short description.